# ASP.NET Core 6, simple Identity management and login/out only through Google, without local store

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, google-authentication, asp.net-core-6.0

I am building a small Blazor server app. I want people to login via Google OAuth and I have a list of email addresses that are allowed in. I built a google app, created credentials, got my client secret/id and I placed this in `Program.cs` after adding `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` package to the project:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:picture", "picture", "URL");
    });

var authorizedEmails = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AuthorizedEmails").Get<string[]>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Email, authorizedEmails)
            .Build();
    }
);
```

And this works initially. Site redirects on access, google authenticates, gives back token and user is logged in. Now, I can no longer logout that user. Because technically I have no identity management at my disposal through this to ease my pain. However when I try to `AddIdentity` or `AddDefaultIdentity` which would create pages and register objects like `SigninManager` (which would provide `SignOutAsync` as in an Individual Identity template) it doesn't work unless I also give it `AddEntityFrameworkStores`. And that is something I do not want, no local store or credentials database, period.

So how do I go about this? Can Identity exist without a store? Do I have to build a custom store just for this simple thing? Or is there some other way I can log out the google user from the site? The cleaner, the better.

PS: Trying to logout via `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();` failed. The user remained logged in.

Comment: I'm confused, what good would a "Logout" function be, if the user was able to just sign back in?

Comment: @mxmissile, let another user login, app will be used in shifts.

Comment: What happens  if you call  `HttpContext.SignOutAsync()`?

Comment: @mxmissile, just added an edit. Nothing happens. Literally, nothing, the user remains logged in. It could be because the token still lives and this is a Blazor app?

Comment: Odd, just tried on my machine and it signed me out, I'm not using Google Auth though, I'm using Microsoft's SSO. `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();`  I wonder if it requires a "scheme" argument. Sorry wasnt more help.

Comment: @mxmissile, ha, it seems to be because of the way Blazor works with a single open connection. Docs says:  *Blazor apps run outside of the context of the ASP.NET Core pipeline. The HttpContext isn't guaranteed to be available within the IHttpContextAccessor, nor is it guaranteed to be holding the context that started the Blazor app.* It seems logging out user from a context makes no sense since the context never ends.